# How can I certify the client?

Tags: c#, security, tcp, certificate, client

I have the following scenario: a client connects over tcp to a server. The client sends his credentials to the server (password, username, mac address). The server validates the credentials and handles the client if the data is correct.

But is this right? I want to ensure that only one (on the user profile registered) computer can use this client. That means the client and the computer must be identified. I'm be sure that my suggestion above are pretty wrong. But how I can do this better?

Comment: well, the mac address will be enough for *casual* users - but mac spoofing is entirely possible by anyone who knows what they are doing... indeed, no matter what you want to put in place, it can probably be spoofed. Heck, they could just make the "genuine install" a VM, and copy the VM... BTW; before the client sends you anything, the first step should be: "the server proves its identity" (typically via an expected certificate)

Comment: Using the MAC (or IP) address might already be sufficient, depending on your threat model (i.e. what you are defending against). Probably it is best to make a risk analysis to assess how likely it is that users will forge their address to circumvent your protection and what the impact of such an attack is.

Comment: @Dirk both mac and IP are tricky; IP is much more volatile (DHCP etc), and that is before considering things like laptops which might use different gateways (the hotel room, an internet cafe, the office, the bus, etc...). Indeed, if the laptop has both wired and wireless it could very well have multiple MACs as well as multiple IPs.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Certainly you're right, my point was not so much whether to use one or the other, my point was rather that a) it's possible to circumvent nearly all protection depending on skill and effort, and b) that it is therefore necessary to actually have a look at the risk associated with our protection being circumvented.

Comment: Okay, this is preety bad. Isn* there any way, so make ensure that only this computer can use this user profile?

Answer (score 1):

This is a tricky problem, for as the comments pointed out, users may fake any machine information to pretend to be another computer.

What I would recommend is that you hash the machine information (e.g. with [SHA-256](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.sha256(v=vs.110).aspx)), so that it isn't immediately obvious *what* information you use to identify a computer. Of course this can always be learned by attackers in multiple ways (monitoring, disassembly, etc).

[Here](http://www.nextofwindows.com/the-best-way-to-uniquely-identify-a-windows-machine/) are some tips on which data you could use to uniquely identify a machine. I would pick several characteristics, put them all together and then hash them. This of course means that if the user changes e.g. his hard drive (and you use its serial to identify the computer), then he cannot connect anymore. I suppose you will need to offer a "re-create key" function anyway in case users switch or modify their computer.

This approach makes it harder to trick your system, by using multiple pieces of information and hashing them, forcing users to a) figure out what information you use and b) how you hash it (definitely use a salt). 
However, it still is very possible to do just that. The question now is: how high are your requirements? A typical user won't be able to bypass this, if that's all you want then it should be sufficient.

I'm not sure whether there can even be a "perfect" solution to this problem, as you want to protect your system from your very user. This means that all encryption keys, certificates or whatever you use is known by and available to the user. On top of that, users have access to your client application and analyze it. They can modify their computer in ways you cannot prevent of forsee. All in all, I think the best you can do is make it a huge pain in the backside to bypass your guards, so much that nobody will want to bother with it / you can minimize the number of users that may do so.

The only other thing I can think of is fancy logging and monitoring on your server, e.g. to detect that a user connected multiple times with his one machine, then alerting you or aborting all but one connection. Again, this can only reduce abuse, but not completely prevent it.